# Using LocalStorage to determine what page open when user return to my book site

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm developing a site that will have some books, I know how to save the last page opened of the book using LocalStorage

Now I want open the last page when the book is opened again.

I just need this,but I don't know how to do it. When the book is opened go to the last page.

I'm using javascript to do it

Updated

```
//Save and restore position

// save position Next
var bookName = (document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title"))
    function salvePositionNext()
   {
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("nav-chapters 
   next"));
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav-chapters next"));
   localStorage.setItem(bookName[0], locationBook[0])

 }

 //Save position Previous
 function salvePositionPrevious()
 {
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("nav-chapters previous"));
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav-chapters previous"));
   localStorage.setItem(bookName[0], locationBook[0])
 }
 //Load Last Page
 function loadLastPage()
 {
   if(localStorage.getItem(bookName[0])){
 location.replace(localStorage.getItem(bookName[0]))
   }
 }
 // End of save and restore position
```

Comment: Do you have a question or a specific problem to resolve?

Comment: Please describe the HTML structure of a book. Is each chapter a separate HTML page, or is the whole book on a single HTML page? Is it possible to create a URL that points to a specific chapter?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Yes, each chapter is a separate HTML and yes, there is `<ol class="chapter">` tree of chapters i think can url points here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  a problem because when i'm calling function the page don't stop refresh

Comment: Got it. So every page load fires an `onload` event that runs `returnPage()` which changes the `document.location` to a different page which then fires an `onload` event that runs `returnPage()` which changes the `document.location` to a different page which then fires an `onload` event that runs `returnPage()` which changes the `document.location` to a different page which then .... get it?

Comment: Yeah, this way. do you have any suggest to solve this?

Comment: No, `locationBook` is the URL to a chapter. 
like this: `nameBook`(I'm using like item) is Title of the book, `locationBook`(I'm using like value of item(nameBook)) is the URL to a chapter.

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish a URL of a book from a URL of a chapter? E.g. if the user opens a book he goes to ``https://website.com/book123`` and if the user goes to a chapter he goes to ``https://website.com/book123/chapter456`` ? Then in function returnPage you can look at location.href and if it contains a chapter id, then don't redirect.

Comment: Yes, each chapters is on other HTML file

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I got it, how do I reverse this downvote in my question?

Answer (score 0):

`Functions` used to save and restore position of a book in my site, the page go to last position is just book `root`. then when this page is loaded go to **URL** `locationBook` (value of bookName key)

```
//Save and restore position

// save position Next
var bookName = (document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title"))
    function salvePositionNext()
   {
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("nav-chapters 
   next"));
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav-chapters next"));
   localStorage.setItem(bookName[0], locationBook[0])

 }

 //Save position Previous
 function salvePositionPrevious()
 {
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("nav-chapters previous"));
   var locationBook = (document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-nav-chapters previous"));
   localStorage.setItem(bookName[0], locationBook[0])
 }
 //Load Last Page
 function loadLastPage()
 {
   if(localStorage.getItem(bookName[0])){
 location.replace(localStorage.getItem(bookName[0]))
   }
 }
 // End of save and restore position
```